# Should the Windows EXE application manifest attached to a .NET assembly have a proper application name and version set?

Tags: .net, exe

Within the Visual Studio project properties for an application there is an option to 'Create application without a manifest'. This option is necessary when deploying an application via [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), but I didn't understand what this option did, and my research so far is as follows...

On disabling the option and recompiling I noticed that the .NET assembly manifest that lists the contents of the assembly was still intact and had not changed. On comparing the binaries (using Hex comparison mode in [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)) I noticed this chunk had been dropped from the end of the EXE image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I believe this is a Windows executable application manifest as described on MSDN ([Application Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa374191%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)):

> An application manifest is an XML file that describes and identifies
>   the shared and private side-by-side assemblies that an application
>   should bind to at run time.

An odd thing here is that the application name and version in the above XML appear to have default values (MyApp, version 1.0.0.0), whereas the Visual Studio project that builds this binary has a proper name and version number defined, so it *seems* to me that all .NET binaries (or EXE files anyway) get this same default WindowsEXE manifest embedded. Is this so? And should I be setting these name and version values somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name as it appears in the manifest is a *logical* name.  There is no need for it to actually match the EXE name.  It is only ever used by Windows in one scenario that the description you found mentions, the "private side-by-side assemblies" case.

Side-by-side assemblies matter in *unmanaged* applications that use DLLs.  It solves a DLL Hell problem, such apps retrieve the DLL by not just the name but also the version.  You'll find the place where these "assemblies" are stored on your machine in c:\windows\winsxs.  Very few commercial programs actually use this feature, it is rather a big headache to take advantage of and the documentation is very poor, you'll almost exclusively find Microsoft DLLs in that directory.  It got bulked up quite a bit since Vista, operating system DLLs are stored there as well.

This might all sound familiar to you, .NET has such a side-by-side directory as well.  Not stored in the same place and not using the same name.  We call it the GAC, the Global Assembly Cache.  The underlying plumbing is otherwise the same but *much* easier to take advantage of since support for the Fusion api is built directly in the CLR.  And doesn't require the manifest hoopla, .NET assemblies already have the necessary attributes in their assembly metadata.  A manifest is however still required in a .NET executable for the *other* things that a manifest does.  The one you posted is important, it tells Windows that your program is UAC aware and doesn't have to be lied to when it does things like writing registry keys in HKLM or copying files to c:\windows.  The application name and version is there because it is not optional.

Long story short, neither the name nor the version in the manifest actually matters for .NET programs.